# Can you force applications to open in full screen?

Tags: snow-leopard

Is there a way, like an app or a system preference, that will open applications in full screen, all the time. By full screen I mean taking up all the screen real estate. I know it doesn't match apple user interface guidelines but I have a friend for whom it would make life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, no. Through the Macs history (as you pointed out with the HIG), Macs have had a 'zoom' feature versus a maximize one like Windows. Many times this will make the window full screen, but not always.

With Mac OS 10.7 due out this summer, having a [full screen application](http://www.apple.com/macosx/lion/) is one of the new features, where the application will take up everything on the screen. Since 10.7 is still under NDA, not sure if there will be a way to have the application always launch full screen or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is an app that will 'fullscreenify' apps until 10.7 is public?

Comment: I found an app called megazoomer (http://ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html) but have never used it. It does say it should support Snow Leopard too. 10.7 is supposed to be out this summer at some point.